# VBA 2010 - Hide all SAP GUI windows using .iconify

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

below is code I have found online to log in to SAP GUI to export data using VBA. I have tailored it to work for what I need it for and it works great. Just one problem, I can't seem to figure out how to hide ALL windows (including the Logon window) using .iconify.

I have basically added `Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify` or `Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify` throughout the code; seems excessive. Most windows will flash open, then hide, but there are some that don't.

It would be nice if there was a way to hide ALL windows completely, even to where they do not flash open. Any ideas?

Also, the logon pad stays open but I have found a way to get rid of it using some API code. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Sub SAPextract()
Dim SAPGUI
Dim Applic
Dim connection
Dim Session
Dim WSHShell

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", vbNormalFocus

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Do Until WSHShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
  Loop

Set WSHShell = Nothing
Set SAPGUI = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Applic = SAPGUI.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = Applic.OpenConnection("******", True)
Set Session = connection.Children(0)
  Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
  Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "100"
  Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = ******
  Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = ******
  Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn[1]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,0]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,1]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,2]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,3]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").caretPosition = 5
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn[17]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,0]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,1]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,2]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,3]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,4]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,5]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,6]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 1
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE").verticalScrollbar.Position = 2
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssub/1/2/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxt[1,7]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press    
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[48]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txt[68]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "******"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[40]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
    
'Export
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 21
Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/rad[1]").Select
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/rad[0]").Select
Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]").iconify
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[0]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").Text = "******"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

Set Session = Nothing
  connection.CloseSession ("ses[0]")
Set connection = Nothing
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with the [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) API functions. You'd need to check to make sure that you can hide the Logon window if it's modal though.  I can't remember offhand.

Comment: Thanks Comintern, I will take a look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I use a workaround for it.

```
 bWindowFound = Wshell.AppActivate("SAP Logon")
  if bWindowFound then
     Wshell.appActivate "SAP Logon"
     WScript.Sleep 200
     Wshell.sendkeys "%{F4}" 
     WScript.Sleep 200
  end if
```

The window will not be closed, but it will land in the taskliste.

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Thanks Scriptman, this works great for the SAP Logon window. Do you have any ideas for my main problem using .iconify?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I do not know how to hide all windows in SAP GUI Scripting. I guess it does not work at all. Iconify is the only thing I know.

Comment: That's ok, thank you for your help! The answer you provided is useful for hiding the SAP Logon window.