# Report sometimes returns 0 records in SAP GUI script

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

So I've recorded a script using the SAP GUI recorder. I'm basically just running 7 reports and saving the contents to an excel file. The code is uninspiring, just some variation of.

`session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "SAP_ALL.TXT"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 11`

But sometimes there are no records in the report.

1. I suspect there is something I can check to either save the report or move on using `if/then/else` but cannot find a good example. How do I catch and recover from this or other errors?
2. Is there a way to to `sapshcut`�or structure the script to avoid this problem?
3. Also, is there a way to execute the script from the command line, passing in the userid and password as parameters?

Relevant examples welcome. I'd RTFM but I don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the report is a grid, then you could try the following.

for example:

```
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
on error resume next
'This command must be recorded once in your environment. It's a   mouseclick in the first line.
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr  /subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 1
if err.number = 0 then
   on error goto 0
   ...
   session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "SAP_ALL.TXT"
   session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 11
   ...
else
   on error goto 0
   ...
end if
...
```

3. Please take a look at the following link:

[VBA 2010 - Hide all SAP windows using .iconify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009935/vba-2010-hide-all-sap-windows-using-iconify)

Regards,
ScriptMan